# How I add my Header and footer in my magento 2 theme

Tags: magento2, theme, header, footer

I am new fresher and start Magento 2 development I have created a Magento 2 theme and I have created a custom header and footer how I add my custom header footer in Magento 2 theme
[image]

[image]

this is my theme view
this is my simple theme folder[image]

and this is my custom header and footer 
how I add this header and footer in this theme

Answer (score 1):

Please check Luma theme,

You can see that header & footer is defined under

**vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html** folder.

So, we have to create Magento_Theme under

```
app/design/frontend/{packagename}/{themename}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml &
app/design/frontend/{packagename}/{themename}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml
```